# Google Colab ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, sequentialfeatureselector

My Initial import looks like this and this code block runs fine.

```
# Libraries to help with reading and manipulating data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Libraries to help with data visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

# Removes the limit for the number of displayed columns
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
# Sets the limit for the number of displayed rows
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 200)

# to split the data into train and test
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# to build linear regression_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# to check model performance
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error, r2_score
```

But when I try to following command I get  the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib'

I tried to use !pip to install all the modules and other suggestions for this error it didnt work. This is google colab so not sure what I am missing

```
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second part you can do this to fix it, I copied the rest of your code as well, and added the bottom part.

```
# Libraries to help with reading and manipulating data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Libraries to help with data visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

# Removes the limit for the number of displayed columns
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
# Sets the limit for the number of displayed rows
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 200)

# to split the data into train and test
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# to build linear regression_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# to check model performance
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error, r2_score

# I changed this part
!pip install mlxtend
import joblib
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.externals.joblib'] = joblib
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS
```

it works for me.

Comment: Thank you but the first part works issue I have is second part

Comment: @Kusek take a look at my answer, it works on colab for me